# Tensorflow Broadcasting across one dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning

I have a tensor A that is [m,n,k] and I have another tensor B that is [m,n]. I would like to add B in an element wise fashion across the k dimension of A. Is there a way of doing this efficiently in TensorFlow? I was looking into broadcast_to but I don't think that is what I'm looking for.

Does the adding operation automatically broadcast? As in, if I did output = A + B explicitly?

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1):

tf.add seems to support broadcasting. Needed to read the documentation more carefully!

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/math/add